# EXTJS, Unable to bind event handler to controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs

I'm using EXTJS with Node.JS and am having difficulty with handling events in the context of the EXTJS MVC framework.

I've been able to easily register click events when defining the Event Listener in the Class Definition of the view, but can't seem to move this code into the controller.

Here's a look at my current code:

```
//Icon.JS (VIEW)

Ext.define('GeekFlicks.view.Icon', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    alias: 'widget.icon',
    height: 48,
    width: 48,
    text: 'icon',
    draggable: true
});
```

//Icon.JS (CONTROLLER)

```
Ext.define('GeekFlicks.controller.Icon', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

models: ['Icon'],
stores: ['Icons'],
views: ['Icon'],

init: function () {
    this.control({          
        'listener': {
            click: function(c) {
                alert('working');
            }
        }
    });
},
});
```

Any help or explanations around how EXTJS deals with these sort of events is will be extremely helpful and much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `this.control` to be something like this:

```
'icon': {
    click: function(c) {
       alert('working');
    }
}
```

You basically need to let controller know which element is going to control. I also suggest reading about using `refs: []` in the controllers to easier access visual elements and views.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Oddly it does not work for "dblclick", but it works for "click" and "mouseover".

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as answered if it suites you.

Comment: It's working, but just for single click. Any idea why dblclick wouldn't be firing?

Comment: May be because button doesn't have dblclick event? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button